# Are there any built-in resources that you can link to from within question to use in a code snippet on the Stack Overflow domain?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-snippets

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28075445/691711), which asks how to be able to start/stop an audio clip on mouse enter/leave. I came back to it while later after seeing the new [runnable code snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and wanted to play around with it by altering [my existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075713/691711).  However, the question pertains to using an `<audio>` tag with audio `<sources>` which have to be loaded.

I know that we are able to use images in code snippets fairly easily and be able to detail an answer, but with media types becoming more and more usable, it would be helpful to have some set of Stack Overflow hosted content that you could include in a snippet as a resource without dealing with cross-origin problems.

Bear in mind, I'm **not** asking for users to be able to upload their own files with questions similar to what [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637/251625) is asking for, I'm talking about static, unwavering, known resources that don't grow in size or change in content.

Also, I'm not asking for a giant HD movie to be hosted on the site, but it would be helpful to be able to throw something like:

```html
<video>
    <source src="examplefiles/vid.webm">
</video>
```

And have it work from within the runnable snippet even if it were just a five second SD animated Stack Exchange logo.

Consider the following runnable that would utilize a statically hosted image (we can do this right now with the Stack Overflow banner image).

```js
var rot = 0;

(function spinImage(timestamp) {
  $("#spinner").css({
    "transform": "rotate(" + (rot++) + "deg)"
  });
  window.requestAnimationFrame(spinImage);
}())
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.cropped {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}
.cropped img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner" class="cropped">
  <img class="cropped" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68">
</div>
```

If not, what are some services for media content, whether it be images, audio, video, or whatever, that you can utilize from within a code snippet without being bothered by cross-origin problems?

An additional note pointed out by **cornergraf** which further emphasizes the benefit of providing statically usable resources.

> It is important that any content used for answers does not suddenly
> disappear or change in the future - this is essentially why link-only
> answers are frowned upon. We can guarantee this only if Stack Overflow
> hosts these resources, using random third-party sites is too risky

Comment: Cool idea, although I could see it being pretty confusing for less experienced users.

Comment: There are a *lot* of file sharing services around, with various degrees of slime attached.  Everybody has their own idea of what kind of slime is acceptable.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I can't see how your comment relates to this question in any way, @Hans.